# Find number of $(A1,A2,...Ak)$ such as $Ai$ is subset of [n] and $|A1 \cap A2 \cap... \cap Ak|=j$

Tags: combinatorics

Here is what I've been thinking

First I choose j elements from [n]

Then for every other element from $n-j$ element that are left I choose whether or not it belongs to $Ai$.

Finaly, since I have k sets the answer is $k {n \choose j} 2^{n-j}$

However I have a feeling I did something wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: I know now you take your matches very seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the $n-j$ elements can be either in or not in each of the sets. Thus it has $2^k-1$ possibilities where we exclude the case that it is in all the sets.

The total is therefore $(2^k-1)^{n-j}$ multiplied by your  ${n \choose j}$.

Comment: Oh I meant  $|A1 \cap... \cap Ak| \subseteq [n]$ .Thanks